# What is the role of the Colonel & who is he in "The Double (2013)"

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-double

I'm talking about [The Double (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1825157/) I find this movie very confusing. And after searching a bit, reading wiki,IMDb synopsis I found that the movie is ambiguous and can be interpreted differently. Reading through whole thread of [Who is James in "The Double (2013)"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23726/question-about-the-movie-the-double-2013), got some idea about the movie.

But who is the Colonel? Is he an imagination too? What's his role in the movie? Simon tried to stand like him, wanted to talk to him. Did Simon think of him as an idol? Was it the only purpose of that character!

At the end of the movie, Colonel appeared in the ambulance and said

> Colonel: "Are there too many like you?"
>
> Simon replied with a smile on his face: "I like to think I'm pretty unique."

Did Colonel really exist in that ambulance? What is that question all about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The film is based on a novella by Dostoyevsky, and at the end of the Dostoyevsky story, the main character suffers a mental break and is put in an asylum. It doesn't make any sense in the context of the film for the colonel to be in the ambulance with Simon, so in all likelihood the colonel's sudden appearance is meant as a reference to the original story, showing that Simon's hallucinating just like his literary counterpart.